# Datetime Parsing - Unable to get back original value

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

```
DateTimeFormatter DATEFORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();

String testDate = "2013-10-26T04:23:14-08:00";

System.out.println(testDate);
System.out.println(DATEFORMAT.parseDateTime(testDate).toString(DATEFORMAT));
```

Output:

```
2013-10-26T04:23:14-08:00
2013-10-26T05:23:14-07:00
```

Why are outputs off by around an hour ? Is there any other parameter I need to specify for converting DateTime back to string ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible daylight savings issue?

Comment: The computer you're running is in the T5 timezone, you're handing it a T4 timezone. They mean the exact same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is using the joda-time library. As the comments above suggest, it's a TZ issue. You can easily convert any of the times into the TZ of your choice or UTC through a method call on the DateTime object. Something along the lines of:

dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

You're getting different results since the default behavior is to print the DateTime in the system's current timezone.